# Can tin foil hats block anything?

Tags: electromagnetism, radio

This is joked about all the time, but...

Can tin foil hats actually block anything? If they can, what frequencies? Is there any research into tin or aluminum foil and radio blocking or amplifying abilities when shaped into a hat?

If they really don't do anything, what would be better? Radio blocking in a hat design that is, not a Faraday cage suit (with matching tie).

---

Edit: people seem to be missing the tags, so I’ll clarify the questions – What frequencies (mainly on the radio range) can tin foil, when shaped into a hat, block or at least attenuate? If not, are there any frequencies that resonate/amplify within the hat? What would work better for signal blocking in this regard (to the head that is)?

Yes this is a funny subject but let's actually take a look at the physics. There are related questions to the hat, but I believe they fall outside the scope here. If someone wants to ask those on the exchange sites, go ahead.

Comment: Shouldn't this be redirected to Skepticism?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I could've asked it over there, but I'm more intrested in the electromagnetic response than the hat's connection to conspiracy/crazy people in their attempt to block non-existant government mind reading rays. A more apt question for the latter might be how far away brain waves can be detected or something.

Comment: I'm already seeing this question generating some joke responses. Not that there's anything wrong with that, but remember that (1) answers should actually _answer the question_ (and then you can supplement that with as many funny links as you want), and (2) comments are mostly meant for suggesting improvements to the post and requesting clarifications. Any idle discussion should go to [chat].

Comment: This seems to be a list-based question. It's also rather unclear what "better" (better at doing what? better in what way?) and "abilities" (psychic abilities? physical abilities?) mean here.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Can tin foil hats actually block anything?

*Anything*?
Sure.
As already noted by Daniel Griscom's answer, tin foil can block several "things" including rain, alpha rays, and electromagnetic radiation with small enough wave length that the radiation cannot diffract around the edges of the hat.

> If they can, what frequencies?

Since you mention frequency let's really focus on electromagnetic radiation.
Foil, being a metal, is very good at reflecting electromagnetic radiation.
You can see this quite easily by looking at a sheet of aluminum/tin foil: it is shiny and you may even see a reflection of yourself.
Physically this happens because electrons can move easily within the foil.
Electromagnetic radiation impinging on the foil causes these electrons to move, and that motion produces new electromagnetic radiation which generates new radiation which destructively interferes with the original incoming radiation. 
This leads to cancellation of the *incoming* wave so that it does not penetrate the foil, and creation of a new *outgoing* wave which is the reflection you see.

Now this isn't the whole story.
Radiation with a wavelength at about the same size as the hat actually winds up resonating inside the hat.
In an effect similar to a vibration of a violin/guitar string, radiation that fits nicely inside the metal cavity formed by the hat actually winds up creating electromagnetic fields which are *bigger* than the incoming field.
You can get a rough idea of how this works on the Wikipedia page for [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance).
It's the same effect as when you blow gently over a bottle and hear a loud hum sound.

> Is there any research into tin or aluminum foil and radio blocking or amplifying abilities when shaped into a hat?

Yes, there is a [sort of famous study from MIT](http://web.archive.org/web/20100708230258/http://people.csail.mit.edu/rahimi/helmet/) where a student looked into this.
They found the resonance effect mentioned above actually made the electromagnetic field strength inside that hats larger:

> *"For all helmets, we noticed a 30 db amplification at 2.6 Ghz and a 20 db amplification at 1.2 Ghz, regardless of the position of the antenna on the cranium. In addition, all helmets exhibited a marked 20 db attenuation at around 1.5 Ghz, with no significant attenuation beyond 10 db anywhere else."*

Note that resonance is not the same thing as amplification.
Amplification means an increase in power; you can only get that if you have a power source, as in a radio receiver which amplifies the signal coming in over the air waves.
Resonance is an effect wherein (at least in this case) the incoming flow of energy winds up being sort of piled up into the hat so that the fields in the hat are larger than the fields coming in.
It doesn't add new energy to the system, it just concentrates it in the hat.

> If they really don't do anything, what would be better? Radio blocking in a hat design that is, not a Faraday cage suit (with matching tie).

Radio waves have pretty big wave length.
For example, a 100 MHz wave has a length of 3 meters.
If you want to block that out you need something like a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) with holes a substantial fraction smaller than that wave length.

P.S. The conclusions in that MIT study are hilarious and I recommend reading it.

Comment: I have neighbours who lined their roofs with tinfoil for the same reason. Does it then resonate inside the bedrooms? I am thinking of rooms in the roof, with sloping ceilings. You mean they actually made the (whatever it was they were afraid of) worse?

Comment: @RedSonja Yes, it's possible that putting foil on the roof has increased the electromagnetic field strength in some places. I'm basing that on general principle, not any specific data.

Comment: Re lining roofs with tin? (Or aluminum?) foil: ask about their phone reception. Tin roofs are normally not "foil" but substantially thicker, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. I have aluminum *paint* on the inside of my roof.  It's useful for its IR emission properties, not to block anything.

Comment: Also, while increasing the frequency of em radiation makes it less susceptible to diffraction, the increased energy increases its ability to _penetrate_ the foil.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Doesn't that only really matter once you get up past x-rays? Certainly in the radio bands the penetration of fields within the metal is exponentially suppressed, so even if the skin depth gets a little bigger you still won't get through much.

Comment: Selecting this as you give details, but can you summarize the MIT study a bit in your answer? Unrelated: the MIT study uses amplified and resonance interchangeably.

Comment: @Status added excerpt from MIT study.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question. Your refraction/cancellation explanation makes me wonder if there would be a difference of the hat were grounded. Foil is commonly used for cable shielding, but it has to be grounded to work. Similar to RedSonja's neighbor I worked with some engineers feigning a recording studio who included a layer of heavy-grade foil in the walls for shielding. They would have grounded it to something. A studio I worked in had chicken wire for the same purpose

Comment: @Tom I don't think grounding a Faraday cage would significantly change how it works.

Comment: @Tom, grounding is necessary to keep the signals generated inside from getting out. When shielding from outside signals, grounding is not necessary if the Faraday cage is a metallic cavity with no holes. If some holes are present (the usual case) grounding probably improves the isolation from outside signals.

Answer (score 125):

A [tin foil hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat) can block:

- [alpha rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle)
- electromagnetic waves, where the wavelength is short enough to not diffract around the edges (counterexample: [FM radio waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting)), but not short enough to punch through the foil (counterexample: [gamma rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray))
- [ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound)
- [rain](https://www.designswan.com/archives/15-creative-and-unusual-umbrella-designs.html)
- [job offers](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/jobsearchtips/a/howtofind.htm)
- [marriage proposals](http://hartford.craigslist.org/about/best/sfo/66795671.html)

But, [then again](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2012/09/tin-foil-hats-actually-make-it-easier-for-the-government-to-track-your-thoughts/262998/)...

Comment: I would like to add x-rays. Depending on the thickness. And the energy. With 2mm of aluminium you should be able to block over 90% of X-rays below 30kV. Not sure, if 2 mm still can be considered foil.

Comment: @Dschoni X-rays are electromagnetic waves, so it's already included. 2mm is not foil.

Comment: 2mm would be "sheet metal", not foil. [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_foil) lists 0.2mm but I also found references to 0.25mm for sale.

Comment: What about beta particles?

Comment: @Dschoni generally, metal with one dimension significantly less than the others (i.e. it's "flat", not wire or shot), where said dimension is less than 0.008 inches (0.2mm) is considered ***foil***. 0.008 inches to 0.25 inches (6.5 mm) is ***sheet***, then beyond 0.25 inches you have ***plate***. As it's just a continuum of thicknesses, the edge of each type can be fudged a bit.

Comment: This now has 3x the votes of my next highest rated answer, which was itself a bit vacuous. My careful, thoughtful answers tend to get low scores. Oh, well...

Comment: @DanielGriscom Hot network questions screw up voting.

Comment: @alex.forencich, beta particles are electrons with an honorific title and relatively high kinetic energy and will bounce harmlessly off human skin most of the time. The hat would have a more than fair chance of actually receiving a net charge from beta radiation, if it manages to otherwise lose its momentum and not simply pop another electron out of the hat, or bounce off.

Comment: They also cannot protect you from falling objects.

Comment: 4x the votes of my next highest rated answer, and counting... oy...

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to point out that blocking UV radiation is useful, as I for one have had sunburn on my head. Foil **could** be used as an improvised "beenie" hat if stuck out in the open, or as a black-out lining of a hat that is more decorative than opaque (e.g. knit fabrics).

Comment: Arguably, not just could tin foil be used, but might actually make a better hat to shield you from the sun, as it would tend to reflect heat away, whereas a traditional hat will tend to absorb heat from the sun.  Since hats are often worn to shield you from the sun in hot weather, this property would be desirable.

Answer (score -7):

Whereas a straight unfolded, uncrumbled piece of tin foil can block out some of the lower wave lengths permeating throughout the atmosphere, a folded or crumpled tin foil hat will not block out anything.

The reason is that tin (aluminium) foil is actually made up of two thin layers.  There is a clear sheet in between the layers to act as a base in the manufacturing process.  If folded or crumpled the aluminium (tin) foil breaks down and creates visible patches throughout the piece.

Try crumpling and then restoring a piece of foil and then hold it up to your face to see the breakdown spots emerge.

In this condition any wavelength would be able to penetrate the layers of foil making the idea of protection moot.

Comment: Are you sure? I know the last rolling pass is done on two sheets (so each is half the thickness of the minimum that can be rolled) but they become two sheets. What kind of transparent base can withstand pizza-oven temperature,  and would bind to the foil?

Comment: I think you are confusing *aluminum foil* with [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallised_film). The question refers to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_foil).

Comment: "*If folded or crumpled the aluminium (tin) foil breaks down and creates visible patches throughout the piece*" You should probably stick with theory based on the scope of the question, rather than practical. In that, let's say the foil (whatever type it is) is not crumpled, has no structural breakdown, (etc) :) Although it would be a valid point to note that different materials might make a difference.

Comment: I think it's valid to bring up the construction methods as well.

Comment: I demonstrate how tinfoil blocks radio and microwave frequencies on a regular basis using folded and crumpled examples.